# Hiding created date not working

Tags: joomla3.8

I've looked at other questions and I've tried what was suggested with no success.  I'm trying to get the created date to not show on my articles.  I've checked the global article setting and the individual settings and they are both set to hide.  If anyone can tell me how to hide the created date on articles would be greatly appreciated.  I'm using Joomla 3.8.1

Answer (score 3):

It can be tricky to find the correct place to set these options. For regular articles, there are three places to set if the date is shown:

1. Global settings
2. Article settings
3. Menu item settings

If you're using a menu item to show a single article, #3 is the safest way to control how the article is displayed. Go to your menu item, click the "Options" tab and change the corresponding settings to "Hide". Note that there are three different dates that can be shown/hidden: Created, Modified and Published.

[image: Date settings]

Comment: Thank you.  I went to menu items -> options and I only have browser page title, show page heading and page class.  I don't see those options.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: What menu item type?

Comment: @M.Mason - the setting is specific for each menu item. Go to Menus -> [Your menu] and click the title of the menu item you want to edit. That's where you'll find the "Options" tab and the date settings.

Comment: ok, I went to the specific menu item that has the articles associated with it and show create date is set to "Use Global (Hide)".  Is it possible there's a bug in 3.8.1 that I'm not aware of that can cause the create date ti still show when it's selected to hide?